# ¿por qué este código no funciona?

Tags: javascript

¿por qué este código me arroja la cadena de texto con la función reverse ya aplicada? puse que me regrese fraseA y en ninguna parte del código le aplique a esta variable la función reverse.

```
function reverso(frase){
  var fraseA = frase.split("");
  var fraseC=fraseA;
  fraseC.reverse();

 return fraseA;
}

var frase=prompt("escribe una frase");
document.write(reverso(frase));
```

Comment: Podrias poner un ejemplo de entrada y salida, para mi que el codigo que tienes es funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque tanto  fraseC como fraseA estan apuntando al mismo objeto por tanto los cambios que apliques en fraceC se verán reflejados en fraseA. En definitiva son dos variables que tienen una referencia al mismo objeto, por este motivo tal comportamiento.

Podrias crear una copia por medio de slice para que fraseA no se vea afectada. Tu código quedaría así:

```
function reverso(frase){ var fraseA = frase.split(""); 
                         var fraseC=fraseA.slice(0); 
                         fraseC.reverse();

return fraseA; 

}

var frase=prompt("escribe una frase"); document.write(reverso(frase));

</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, soy nuevo en esto. Como puedo hacer para que las dos variables sean independientes?, excluyendo la parte donde obtengo el valor de una sobre la otra

Comment: Si ves mi respuesta con slice podes hacer una copia. Te adjunte ejemplo de tu código como quedaría y capturas de pantalla. Si te sirvio mi respuesta acordate de aceptarla. Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Las dos variables estan referenciando a un mismo objeto, entonces la solucion seria crear otra variable para que pueda ser independiente:

**pregunta:como hacerlo independiente?**

**respuesta**: var fraseC=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( fraseA ));

```js
function reverso(frase) {
  var fraseA = frase.split("");
  var fraseC = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( fraseA ));
  fraseC.reverse();
  console.log(fraseA.toString());
  console.log( fraseC.toString());
  return fraseA;
}
reverso('hola mundo');
```

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente en programación hay tres formas de manipular el valor de los datos que almacenamos en variables:

- Podemos **copiar** el valor de una variable en otra
- Lo podemos pasar como **argumento** a través de una función
- Lo podemos **comparar** con otro valor.

El manejo de la variable de tu pregunta se encuentra claramente en ese primer ámbito de **copiar**. En Javascript hay fundamentalmente dos maneras de manipular valores: ***por valor*** o ***por referencia***. Vamos a explicar cada una:

### Por valor

Cuando un dato se manipula "por valor", es el valor del dato lo que importa: en una asignación, **se realiza una copia del valor real** y esa copia se almacena en una propiedad de variable u objeto o elemento de matriz; **la copia y el original son dos valores totalmente independientes que se almacenan por separado**.

Cuando se pasa un dato "por valor" a una función, se pasa una copia del dato a la función; si la función modifica ese valor, el cambio afecta solo a la copia de la función del dato; no afecta al dato original.

Y cuando un dato se compara "por valor" con otro dato, los dos datos distintos deben representar exactamente el mismo valor (lo que generalmente significa que una comparación byte a byte los encuentra iguales).

---

### Por referencia

Con esta técnica, **solo hay una copia real del dato**, y se trata de referencias a ese dato que se manipulan. Cuando un dato se manipula "por referencia", solo hay una copia del valor real. Si un valor se manipula "por referencia", las variables no mantienen ese valor directamente; solo tienen referencias al mismo. Son estas referencias las que se copian, pasan y se comparan.

Entonces, en una asignación hecha "por referencia", es la referencia al valor que se le asigna, no una copia del valor, y no el valor mismo. Después de la asignación, la nueva variable contendrá la misma referencia al valor que contiene la variable original. **Ambas referencias son igualmente válidas, y ambas se pueden usar para manipular el valor; si el valor se cambia a través de una referencia, ese cambio también aparecerá a través de la referencia original**.

La situación es similar cuando se pasa un dato a una función "por referencia": se pasa una referencia al valor a la función, y la función puede usar esa referencia para modificar el valor en sí mismo; cualquiera de esas modificaciones será visible fuera de la función.

Y finalmente, cuando un dato se compara con otro "por referencia", las dos referencias se comparan para ver si se refieren a la misma copia única de un valor; las referencias a dos datums distintos que tienen el mismo valor (consisten en los mismos bytes) no se tratarán como iguales.

---

En Javascript, cuando se hace la asignación de una variable a otra mediante el signo `=`, se hace una asignación **por referencia**. De modo que, cualquier cambio que hagas a la nueva variable, o a la antigua, afectará al valor del objeto, ya que lo que estás manipulando en esa variable es una referencia a un mismo objeto. En pocas palabras: *existe un mismo objeto, con un solo valor, y dos referencias a ese objeto*.

Para evitar esto hay varios métodos. Aquí por ejemplo, creamos **una nueva instancia** de objeto llamada `fraseC` y le asignamos el valor de `fraseA`. De este modo, los cambios que ocurran sobre `fraseC` no afectarán a `fraseA`.

```js
function reverso(frase) {
  var fraseA = frase.split("");
  var fraseC = Array.from(fraseA);
  fraseC.reverse();
  console.log(fraseC);
  return fraseA;
}

var frase = prompt("escribe una frase");
document.write(reverso(frase));
```

---

- Para más detalles puedes leer el interesante artículo [***By Value vs. By Reference***](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/web/jscript/ch09_03.html) del libro **JavaScript the Definitive Guide**

Comment: Gracias, esto resolvió mis dudas. Con esto puedo abordar los problemas con mas claridad

Comment: Me alegro de que la respuestas te hayan ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** en el Centro de Ayuda, @CarlosMorfinDiaz